# Trigger Lambda on deploy API in API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cloudwatch

I'm trying to trigger a Lambda function when I click on deploy in the API-Gateway console to deploy API on a stage.

I already tried with cloudwatch rule, but there is no event patterns for API-Gateway deployment.

*My questions are:*

Is it possible to trigger a lambda function when I click on the deploy button on API-Gateway console?

If yes, how can I do that?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no straight forward way for achieving this.
CloudWatch rule will not help as there is no logging generated on API deployment.
The only thing left behind a deploy action is a CloudTrail event.

The best solution I could think for this involves [Amazon EventBridge](https://aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/) which is an event bus managed service provided by AWS.

In EventBridge you can create rules that collect specific events from various AWS services within (and beyond) your AWS account.

API Gateway is not one of these services, **but CloudTrail is**! (For reference [here is a list](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/event-types.html#events-for-services-not-listed) of the EventBridge supported services)

An API deployment in API Gateway emits an event to CloudTrail which has `CreateDeployment` as event name and `apigateway.amazonaws.com` as event source. The event payload also includes data such as the `restApiId`, the stage, the IAM identity details of the deploying agent and more.

*Note, that there is not much documentation around CloudTrail event schemas, but the event would look something like the one listed [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/cloudtrail.html)*

Now, we need to create an EventBridge rule that captures such CloudTrail events.
**[This is a very good, step by step, guide on how to do this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/create-eventbridge-cloudtrail-rule.html).**

For your use case, you need to choose `API Gateway` as the service name and add `CreateDeployment` as a Specific Operation as shown in the screenshot below:

[image]

Once the EventBridge rule is set up then you can directly attach it as a trigger in any Lambda function. [See relevant tutorial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/run-lambda-schedule.html).

### Downsides

The above solution cannot be applied on the individual API level. The EventBridge rule will capture the deployments of all APIs of any stage in a specific region. Additional filtering has to be implemented within the lambda logic.

This will lead to unnecessary lambda executions if the solution is scoped for anything less than all the APIs of a region. However as we're talking about API deployments, the extra lambda execution cost will be negligible.